# ValueError: Invalid parameter learning_rate for estimator KerasRegressor

Tags: gridsearchcv

This issue can likely be resolved by setting this parameter in the KerasRegressor constructor:
`KerasRegressor(learning_rate=0.1)`Check the list of available parameters with `estimator.get_params().keys()`

Normally I use keras.wrappers.scikit_learn, but when I switch to sciKes.wrappers I get this error. can anyone give me some help, because previously I didn't get any error when using keras.wrappers.scikit_learn. And I'm having a hard time understanding the meaning of the scikeras.wrappers documentation.

here my code :

```
def build_model(optimizer, learning_rate, neurons):
    grid_model = Sequential()
    grid_model.add(keras.layers.LSTM(X_train.shape[2],input_shape = (X_train.shape[1],X_train.shape[2]),return_sequences = True))
    grid_model.add(LSTM(neurons))
    grid_model.add(Dense(1))

    if optimizer == 'adam':
        optimizer = Adam(learning_rate=learning_rate)
    elif optimizer == 'rmsprop':
        optimizer = RMSprop(learning_rate=learning_rate)
    else :
        optimizer = SGD(learning_rate=learning_rate)

    grid_model.compile(optimizer = optimizer, loss = 'mean_squared_error')
    return grid_model

grid_model = KerasRegressor(build_fn=build_model,verbose=1,validation_data=(X_val,Y_val),shuffle=False)

parameters = {'neurons' : [8, 16, 32, 64],
              'batch_size' : [16, 32, 64, 128],
              'epochs' : [200],
              'optimizer' : ['adam', 'rmsprop', 'sgd'],
              'learning_rate' : [1e-1, 1e-2, 1e-3, 1e-4, 1e-5] }

grid_search  = GridSearchCV(estimator = grid_model,
                            param_grid = parameters,
                            cv = 2)

grid_search = grid_search.fit(X_train, Y_train, shuffle=False, callbacks=callbacks_list)
```

With the same code I didn't have any problems with keras.wrappers.scikit_learn, but now I have to use sciKes. Because I had to use visual studio code, which no longer supports keras.wrappers.scikit_learn